# Swear Word Filter - output from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html form that saves **name** and **comment** to a MySQL database.  The **name** and **comment** entries are then displayed in a table format on a php page.

I want to have any swear words from the comment field to appear as **three asterisks** when displayed in the PHP outputted table.

I got it to work as follows:

**swear.php**

```
<?php 
    $find = array("BadWord1","BadWord2","BadWord3"); //words I don't want displayed
    $replace = array("***","***","***"); //The replacements 
    ?>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
        //connect to the database 
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'db') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

        //connect to swear.php
        require("swear filter.php");



        //process the form & email
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['name']));
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));

        $comment= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comment']));
        $comment=str_replace($find, $replace, $comment);

        $from = 'From: whoever'; 
        $to = 'anemail@something.com'; 
        $subject = 'Hello';
        $human = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['human']);

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $comment";

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
                if ($human == '4') {                 
                    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                    echo '<h1 class=\"meantime\"></h1>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<h1 class=\"meantime\">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</h1>'; 
                } 
            } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<h1 class=\"incorrect\">You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</h1>';
            }
            } else {
                echo '<h1 class=\"required\">You need to fill in all required fields!!</h1>';
            }

        }
        ?>


        <?php
        //connect to the database 
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'db') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

        //create the insert statement
        $query = "INSERT INTO table(name, email, comment, date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$comment', now())";

        //insert record into the table
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');

        //close connection to database
        mysqli_close($dbc);

        //display thank you to user and link back to form page
        print "<br>";
        print "<h2 class=\"meantime\">Nice 1 <span class=\"nice\"> " .  stripslashes($name) .  "</span>.  I shall check it out.</h1>";
        print "<h3 class=\"meantime\">In the meantime, see what others have posted.</h3>";
        print "<br><br>";
        print "<h3 class=\"meantime\"><a href=\"comments.php\"><span class=\"underline\">Comments so far</span></a></h3>";
        print "<br><br>";
        ?>
```

Is there a more efficient way of completing the **swear.php** file.

1. Do I have to type the **three asterisks** for each replacement badword - since it is the same all the time?

Is there a better way overall of implementing a simple swear word filter?

Thanks for any help, Andy ;-)

Comment: `$comment=str_replace($find, '***', $comment);`

Comment: @dave That won't work.... you'll replace all sorts of things that shouldn't be replaced.

Comment: @Brad aka "the Scunthorpe problem"

Comment: It will turn into a big "hbuttle"

Comment: @Alnitak Exactly!  Thank you, I knew there was a name for it but I couldn't remember.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21343682/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15552300/

Comment: there are no *bad* words; just *bad* word useage

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791792/filtering-words-from-text-with-exploits

Comment: Aka [The Clbuttic Mistake](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/5552.aspx)

Comment: That was ridiculously easy! That's what happens when you stare at a screen for too long! Thank you very much Dave ;-) One other thing though, if I have a different case on the swear words in the array than what a user types e.g. **BadWord1** and they type **badword1**, it does not find it and place in asterisks.  How could I take this into account?  Thanks again Andy ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the follow up comments & links, I will check them out too, Andy ;-)

Comment: @AndyR - if you don't care about capitalization use `str_ireplace`

Comment: you do realise every one is simply saying you should not do this in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

I collected 2200 bad words in 12 languages: en, ar, cs, da, de, eo, es, fa, fi, fr, hi, hu, it, ja, ko, nl, no, pl, pt, ru, sv, th, tlh, tr, zh.

MySQL dump, JSON, XML or CSV options are available.

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

You can check if comment has words from this table and replace using PHP `str_replace` function.